# how to create a 2d array [n,3] getting string input from the user in c# c sharp

Tags: c#, arrays, string, matrix, input

I wrote this code that sum the elements vertically and horizontally. My problem is creating the 2d array from string input. The user should input a string like `"2 1 6"` on a single line (separated by space) and I must to convert into integer each number. The first input of the code represent the number of next lines with strings like `"2 1 6"`. For example, input:

```
2           // the first input line 
2 1 6      // the 2nd input line with the string
3 1 8     //  the 3nd input line with the string
```

The array should be: `int [,] arr = {{2,1,6},{3,1,8}}`
My code:

```
using System;

namespace Exercises
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(input1);
            
            string input2 = Console.ReadLine();
            string[,] strArr = new string[n, 3];
  
            int rows, cols;                   

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    strArr[i, j] = input2.Split(' ')[i];                    
                }
            }            
            rows = strArr.GetLength(0);
            cols = strArr.GetLength(1);

            int[,] intArr = new int[strArr.GetLength(0), strArr.GetLength(1)];
            
            for (int i = 0; i < strArr.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < strArr.GetLength(1); i++)
                {
                    intArr[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(strArr[i, j].ToString());
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                {
                    int sumRow = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                    {
                        sumRow += intArr[i, j];
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Livada " + (i + 1) + ": " + sumRow);
                }
            string[] treesName = { "Meri", "Peri", "Ciresi" };
            for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
             {
                    int sumCol = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
                    {
                        sumCol += intArr[j, i];

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine($"{treesName[i]}: " + sumCol);
                }


            }

        }
    }
```

Is anybody here who can help me with that? Thank you!

Comment: Is this [C#] or what language? Please add the appropriate tag in question.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question and the tags. Is my first question here...Thanks.

Comment: What's input on first line `2`? Each row must have the same number of columns? Question is very, very unclear

Comment: The first input line of the code represent the number of next lines with strings like "2 1 6"

Comment: If the question about diagonal ever came back in a answerable format. Please ping me with @myname.

Comment: I repost the question about diagonals, @DragandDrop
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64448219/check-if-some-elements-are-equal-in-2d-array-c-sharp-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program reads the numbers from the `Console` and fills in the array. The key here is using the `.Split()` method to split a line input to an array of string, separated by the spaces.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        var n = int.Parse(input);

        int[,] intArr = new int[n, 3];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            var parts = input.Split(' ');

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                intArr[i, j] = int.Parse(parts[j]);
            }                
        }
        // intArray has the values from the input
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you assume that there will be only 3 numbers on each line?

Comment: because this is the exercise, with only 3 element on each row.

Comment: I followed the assumption of the _op_. This is definitely a `Dcoder` challenge question and the inputs are defined and not arbitrary.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot, helped me to solve my exercise. Thank you!!!

Comment: Hey, @JohnAlexiou! I gave you the vote up now. I hope is ok even now :)