# Check if some elements are equal in 2D array c# sharp

Tags: c#, arrays, string, for-loop, methods

Given the array:

string[,] arr = new string[n,n].
How do you check if the elements are equal for each row, for each column and for the two diagonals?

It is a kind of tic tac toe: Write a console application that receives as input date N moves of X and 0 as coordinates. (0, 0) is the top left corner and (2, 2) is the bottom right corner. On the first line is the number of moves N, and from line two there are moves, one on each line. The first move is of the player with X, followed by the move of the player with 0, then again X and so on.The application will analyze the received moves and will display the winner: X, 0 or draw if there is no winner.
This is what i tried, but no result:

```
static void Main()
    {
        int numberOfMoves = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        const int size = 3;
        string[,] boardGame = new string[size, size];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMoves; i++)
        {
            string strCoordinates = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] lineCoordinates = strCoordinates.Split(' ');
            int coordinateX = Convert.ToInt32(lineCoordinates[0]);
            int coordinateY = Convert.ToInt32(lineCoordinates[1]);
            const int value = 2;
            boardGame[coordinateX, coordinateY] = i % value == 0 ? "X" : "0";
        }

        // CheckElements(boardGame); in construction
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void CheckRows(int x, int y)
    {
        string[,] boardGame = new string[3, 3];
        int cols = boardGame.GetLength(1);
        const int value = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
        {
            if ((boardGame[0, 0] == boardGame[0, 1] && boardGame[0, 1] == boardGame[0, value]) || (boardGame[1, 0] == boardGame[1, 1] && boardGame[1, 1] == boardGame[1, value]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(boardGame[0, 0]);
            }

            if ((boardGame[1, 0] == boardGame[1, 1] && boardGame[1, 1] == boardGame[1, value]) || (boardGame[value, 0] == boardGame[value, 1] && boardGame[value, 1] == boardGame[value, value]))
            {
                Console.Write(boardGame[0, 0]);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(boardGame[x, y]);
    }

    static void CheckColumns(int x, int y)
    {
        string[,] boardGame = new string[3, 3];
        int rows = boardGame.GetLength(0);
        const int value = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            if ((boardGame[0, 0] == boardGame[1, 0] && boardGame[1, 0] == boardGame[value, 0]) || (boardGame[0, 1] == boardGame[1, 1] && boardGame[1, 1] == boardGame[value, 1]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(boardGame[0, 0]);
            }

            if ((boardGame[0, 1] == boardGame[1, 1] && boardGame[1, 1] == boardGame[value, 1]) || (boardGame[0, value] == boardGame[1, value] && boardGame[1, value] == boardGame[value, value]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(boardGame[0, 1]);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(boardGame[x, y]);
    }

    static void CheckDiagonals(int x, int y)
    {
        string[,] boardGame = new string[3, 3];
        int m = boardGame.Length;
        const int value = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            m--;
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                if (boardGame[0, 0] == boardGame[1, 1] && boardGame[1, 1] == boardGame[value, value])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(boardGame[0, 0]);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(boardGame[x, y]);
    }
```

Comment: You haven't included the `CheckElements(string[,] boardGame)` function in your example.

Comment: @Creyke, it is true, i did not write the function CheckElements because i am stuck. I am looking first for a better solution to check equal elements in rows, colomns and diagonals. i updated my code including a comment at line you referred.

Comment: instead X and Y use 1 and -1 then pseudocode `int[max] rows, int  cols[max] , int diag[2] for(int x <max) { for(int y < max) { cols[x] += board[x,y]; rows[y] += board[x,y]; } diag[0] += board[x,x]; diag[1] += board[max-1-x, x]; }`  now check if any of cols rows or diag is max or -max then someone wins

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given a square matrix there is a way to do all the check in a single loop.
But before going for optimisation let's clean up and simplify.

Given the following square matrix, It may be hard to make all commutation to find the winner.

```
var input = new [,]{
    {"x","x","x"},
    {"x","x","o"},
    {"x","o","o"},
};
```

But if we were able to slice into  Rows, Column, and Diagonals .
It will be easier to to find a winner given `{"x","x","x"},` or `{"x","x","o"}`.

#### Rows / Columns

Based on your previous questionb you already that on a 2D array we can num the number of Cols and Rows using `GetLength(1)` and `GetLength(0)`.

For this example the first row indexes are :
`{ (0,0), (0,1), (0,2) }`.

```
static string[] GetRow(string[,] source, int rowNumber)
{
    var rows = source.GetLength(0);
    var result = new string[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        result[i] = source[rowNumber, i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Naturally for columns we will have the same code:

```
static string[] GetColumn<T>(string[,] source, int columnNumber)
{
    var cols = source.GetLength(1);
    var result = new string[cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        result[i] = source[i, columnNumber];
    }
    return result;
}
```

#### Diagonals

Lets name the diagonal using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_diagonal.
The main diagonal indexes will be `{(0,0) , (1,1), (2,2)}`.
It's look like the same loop but with (i,i)

```
string[] GetSquareMatrixMainDiagonal(string[,] source)
{// {(0,0) , (1,1), (2,2)}

    var cols = source.GetLength(0);
    var rows = source.GetLength(1);
    if (cols != rows) // diagonal will not work on not square matrix.
        throw new ArgumentException($"2D Array [{rows},{cols}], is not a Square matrix");

    var result = new string[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        result[i] = source[i, i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

For the Anti Diagonal indexes will be `{(0,2) , (1,1), (2,0)}`.
Rows is incrementing from 0 > 1 > 2.
While columns are doing the contrary. 2 > 1 > 0

```
static string[] GetSquareMatrixAntiDiagonal(string[,] source)
{
    var cols = source.GetLength(0);
    var rows = source.GetLength(1);
    if (cols != rows) throw new ArgumentException($"2D Array [{rows},{cols}], is not a Square matrix");

    var result = new string[rows];
    var row = 0;
    var col = rows - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        result[i] = source[row++, col--];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here a simple example of getting Rows, Columns and Diagonals:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/FjPIqY

#### Winner?

Now that we have a way to get Slice of the 2d array like `{"x","x","o"}`. We need way to compare all the elment of an array to find if they are the same.
We will save the value of the first element. And check if All the others are equals to it.

```
static string Winner(string[] source)
{
    var val = source.First();
    var isTheSame = source.Skip(1).All(x => x == val);
    return isTheSame ? val : default(string);
}
```

Carefull this will return empty value as a winner on `{"","",""}`.
But we can simply rules this one out in the final check.

Here is an other version without LinQ. And proper handling of empty string and default value fo an empty cell.
*Disclaimer: valid symbols used in this method does not match the fiddle input.*

```
static bool CheckWinner(string[] source, out string winnerSymbol)
{
    winnerSymbol= "-"; // "-", arbitrary representation of an empty cell. 1 char for simple layout.
    
    var firstVal = source[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < source.Length; i++){ 
        if(source[i] != firstVal){
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    // Will be nice to have valid Symbols in an array.
    if(firstVal!= "0" && firstVal != "X"){      
        return false;
    }
    
    winnerSymbol = firstVal;
    return true;
}

static void ExampleUsageOf_CheckWinner(){
    var winInput= new []{"0","0","0"};  
    var looseInput= new []{"0","0","X"};


    if(CheckWinner(winInput, out string winnerSymbol)){
        Console.WriteLine( winnerSymbol +"is a Winner in winInput")
    }
    else{
        Console.WriteLine( "No winner in winInput!")
    }
    
    
    if(CheckWinner(looseInput, out string winnerSymbol)){
        Console.WriteLine( winnerSymbol +"is a Winner in looseInput")
    }
    else{
        Console.WriteLine( "No winner in looseInput!")
    }
}
```

#### Re Factorisation

All methode work the same way: A loop on number of rows or columns.
But in a square matric number of rows and column are the same..
In order to get All the row we will need a loop in order to not write:

```
var r1 = GetRow(input, 0);
var r2 = GetRow(input, 1);
var r3 = GetRow(input, 2);
```

If you rename the "number of rows or columns" into size. After checking that it's a square matrix.
Every methods may be able to be in the same loop. Let try to merge `GetRow` and `GetColumn` to illustrate: with `col_row_index = 0;` for the first row and column.

```
var size = source.GetLength(0);

var currentColumn = new string[size]; // old result variable
var currentRow = new string[size];    // old result variable

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    currentColumn[i] = source[i, col_row_index];
    currentRow[i] = source[col_row_index, i];
}
```

We now can check if one of them is the winner :

```
var winnerC = Winner(currentColumn);
var winnerR = Winner(currentColumn);

if(winnerC != ""){
    // Stop everything! We have a winner 
    // Console.WriteLine + Break, if we are in a loop.
    // Set a boolean to true, if we use some State machine.
    // Return if we are in method
}

if(winnerR != ""){ // Same
}
```

[Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7LH0EG).

I let you do the merge for the diagonal. And you should be able to do the whole board checking with minor modification.

Comment: Thank you, @DragandDrop for explanations. Now I am trying to re-write the code. I will let you know when I am done. Thanks again!

Comment: When someone is writing tic tac toe as a console program, I perhaps wouldn't jump to a LINQ based solution unless you know for sure that LINQ comes before "arrays and loops" in their syllabus

Comment: I think you are right, for sure I haven't studied LINQ yet.

Comment: @CaiusJard, but the only LinQ is the Winner check in a 1d array.  This one is your answer it's 3 lines of code. The same for loop but this time starting from 1 not 0.

Comment: @CaiusJard, I hope that you don't look at the fiddle and discover that the methods are generics.

Comment: @SimonaM. When re writing : Do it step by step and for now. Do not focus on user inputs and turn.
Have a simple exemple grid like in the fiddle in this answers. 

Accept repetition of code till you have a working example. but have a clear separation of purpose. 
Don't mix everything together.

Accept restriction of scope, switching from NxN grid to hard code 3x3, if it helps.

Don't strat factoring without goal: reducing loop on the gird or reducing performance.

Comment: LinQ alternative added. With some fluff, in order to illustrate handeling of empty string

Comment: @DragandDrop oh well, maybe chuck some reflection and a erbservice call in for good measure :). ps; it wasn't a spur to do more of the homework..

Comment: @DragandDrop, Finally, I wrote my tic tac toe, thanks to your suggestions. Here is my code, if you wanna take a look: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ucAlQW
 Thank you again!

Comment: @SimonaM., But tic tac toc is not with N size grid. For 3 by 3 the easiest way was to consider the winning as a byte array. For example winning the first row is `{{1,1,1}{0,0,0}{0,0,0}}` => flatern to `{1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}`. https://codepen.io/labiej/post/using-bit-logic-to-keep-track-of-a-tic-tac-toe-game.  Don't thanks me for the brain teaser.

Comment: This will works for grid with fixed length when you can precompute winning condition. The evaluation is then really simple. Btw Im looking at you final implementation. Do you accept honnest critism?

Comment: @DragandDrop, yes, of course. Tell me! I only followed the exercise, that's why the fixed length. the letter N represent the number of moves (number of coordinates input user and not the size of array).

Comment: Write a console application that receives as input data N moves of X and 0 as coordinates. (0, 0) is the top left corner and (2, 2) is the bottom right corner.
On the first line is the number of moves N, and from line two are the moves, one per line. The first move is of the player with X, followed by the move of the player with 0, then again X and so on.
The application will analyze the received moves and will display the winner: X, 0 or draw if there is no winner.

Comment: My point is if it's not a modular size grid, and if the grid is small enough then iterating the grid is not the fastest/cleanest solution. All the test will literraly boil down to slap 9 byte array together, in ~5-10 lines of code. But that's just a brain teaser. Now for your code there is a ton off little thing. But the mains issues are: 1/. Thats a ton of iteration! maybe dont "checkCols" twice if it's a Cols win. you could have store that result. 2/. while extremly readable Separating Cols/Rows and Diagonal Check, means that you are doing at least 4 times the same jobs.

Comment: 1/. Will be easly solve once you get accustomed with the out parameter. The 2/. point is more trade off, it will be harder to read be you will iterate all the cols and row only once.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly homework, so I'm not going to do it for you, but I'll go throuh your code and drop a comment in where i think something is wrong and how it needs to be changed:

```
    //i think this method should take the game board as a parameter, not x and y
    //because your game oard is populated in the main as a variable that is not accessible anywhere
    //outside the main
    static void CheckRows(int x, int y)
    {
        //this should be an input parameter, rather than being declared here
        string[,] boardGame = new string[3, 3];
   
        //ok this gets the number of columns..
        int cols = boardGame.GetLength(1);

        //..but where is the same thing for rows? I know it's a square board but
        //it's easy to code up the rows too, for ultimate flexibility

        //what's this for? looks like you're limiting yourself to 3x3 boards?
        const int value = 2;

        //i'd have probably called this variable col, or c
        //and I'd probably start it at 1...
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
        {
            //you declared i but you don't use it? You have a loop that increments
            //a number through 0, 1, 2, 3 ... just like you've hard coded here
            //so think about what you hardcoded and how you could do that in a loop
            // - see later for a hint

            if ((boardGame[0, 0] == boardGame[0, 1] && boardGame[0, 1] == boardGame[0, value]) || (boardGame[1, 0] == boardGame[1, 1] && boardGame[1, 1] == boardGame[1, value]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(boardGame[0, 0]);
            }

            //ok, so now you've moved onto hard coding row number 1, and hard coding
            //a bunch of columns.. think about how you could use the variables you have
            if ((boardGame[1, 0] == boardGame[1, 1] && boardGame[1, 1] == boardGame[1, value]) || (boardGame[value, 0] == boardGame[value, 1] && boardGame[value, 1] == boardGame[value, value]))
            {
                Console.Write(boardGame[0, 0]);
            }
        }

        //what is this for?
        Console.WriteLine(boardGame[x, y]);
    }
```

OK, so in there I talked about hints.

When you're checking if every element in a single array is the same, the easiest thing to do is compare every one of them to the first:

```
int[] nums = new[]{2, 2, 2, 2, 2};

//get the first number
int first = nums[0]; //it's always at 0

//use a loop to check if all are the same. use a boolean to remember it
bool allSame = true; //be optimistic..

for(int i = 1; i < nums.Length; i++){ //start from second, not first
  if(nums[i] != first){
    allSame = false; 
    break;
  }
}
```

Can you see how we made this variable? It can check a thousand entries in an array to see if they're the same. As soon as any element isn't the same as the first, we set `allSame` to false and stop looping (no point carrying on)

Then we can examine the value of allSame and see if it's the same or not

---

There is no difference between a 1D array and a 2D array here if you're only checking a single dimension:

```
int[,] nums = new int[,]{{2,2,2},{3,4,5},{4,3,2}};

int first = nums[0,0];
for(int c = 1; c < nums.GetLength(1); c++){

  if(nums[0, c] == first) ...
```

All we did was add the dimension as a hard coded thing... Row 0. The column c is a variable.

But what if we wanted to make it a variable so we check ALL of the dimensions?

Use two loops

```
for(int r = 0; r < nums.GetLength(0); r++){ //rows start from 0!

  int first = nums[r, 0]; //row is variable, column is first
  for(int c = 1; c < nums.GetLength(1); c++){ //cols start from 1!

    if(nums[r, c] == first) //r will be 0, while c goes 1..3, then r will be 1 while c is 1..3 etc
```

All we did to add row checking was add another wrap around the bit that checks a single column, which provided an incrementing value for `r`

---

When it comes to cehcking columns, the logic is the same, it's just that we increment r repeatedly for each c (c is 0 and r goes from 1..3, c is 1 and r is 1..3, c is 2 and r is 1..3)

---

When it comes to checking diagonals it's simpler; we only need one variable that starts at 1, because these are the checks we want to do:

```
x[0,0] compared to x[1,1]
x[0,0] compared to x[2,2]
x[0,0] compared to x[3,3]
x[0,0] compared to x[4,4]

..
```

Which means you can use just one variable because the number repeats:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ... )

  if(x{0,0] == x[i,i])
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, @Caius Jard for your answer. I am trying to rewrite the code. Thanks again!

Comment: //what's this for? looks like you're limiting yourself to 3x3 boards?
        const int value = 2;
This value represent the index 2 and I store this variable because my Visual Studio forced me with an error, otherwise I couldn't run the program, that's why.